# Debian 8 install in QEMU/KVM guest failing due to ext4-fs / "read only filesystem" errors

Tags: debian, filesystems, kvm, qemu, debian-installer

I am on Debian 8.2 and trying to install a Debian 8.2 QEMU/KVM guest. I created a virtual disk image file and booted into the Debian installer ISO with the following commands:

```
jesse@deb:~/vms$ qemu-img create deb-unstable.img 20G
Formatting 'deb-unstable.img', fmt=raw size=21474836480 

jesse@deb:~/vms$ qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -k en-us -cdrom debian-8.2.0-amd64-netinst.iso -hda deb-unstable.img -boot d
```

When I get to the "Install base system" step of the Debian installer it fails with the following errors :

[image]

[image: console 4 error messages - ext4s remounting filesystem read-only]

It seems like for some reason, an error in the EXT4-fs module is causing the virtual disk file to be mounted read-only. But even after reading through various bug reports that seem like they might be related, e.g:

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42723
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1423672

I can't quite figure out what to make of this. Is there something simple I'm doing wrong, or is this something that I should message a bug report list about?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the problem, and wanted to share the solution in case anyone else has the same issue.

Watching the installer output more carefully in console 4 (`ALT+F4` in the guest), I noticed that prior to the `ext4-fs` error, there is an "out of memory" error that is happening during the partitioning/mounting stage, which is the root cause:

[image: out of memory error during partitioning stage]

By default, QEMU only gives 128MB to the virtual machine, which is what was causing the out of memory errors.

**To fix this I had to allocate more memory to the VM (`qemu -m 900` worked for me).**

Answer (score 0):

Often, the filesystem is mounted as read only if there is an issue with the filesystem(not necessarily a problem.)

I have found running fsck fixes this, and make sure you have root access.

Check [Can one scan with fsck a read-only partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82534/can-one-scan-with-fsck-a-read-only-partition) for more help.